# if command in python

Tags: python

```
if "aa" or "bb" or "cc" or "dd" or "ee" or "ff" in attrs["show"]:
    self.xx = xxxx
```

I have a code like this, to check if attrs["show"] contains either of these strings, then assign some value to self.xx

But is this "IF" command is correct? Because from my results, it seems like this if command is always true(which is impossible)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if any(s in attrs["show"] for s in ("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff")):
    self.xx = xxxx
```

Your current if statement will always evaluate to `True`, because instead of checking if each string is in `attrs["show"]` you are checking if `"aa"` is True, or if `"bb"` is True, and on and on.  Since `"aa"` will always evaluate as True in a Boolean context, you will always enter the `if` clause.

Instead, use the [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function as in my example, which accepts an iterable and returns True if any of its elements are True.  Similar to a bunch of `or`'s as in your code, this will short-circuit as soon as it finds an element that is True.  In this example, the above code is equivalent to the following (but much more concise!):

```
if ("aa" in attrs["show"] or "bb" in attrs["show"] or "cc" in attrs["show"] or
    "dd" in attrs["show"] or "ee" in attrs["show"] or "ff" in attrs["show"]):
    self.xx = xxxx
```

Comment: A set would be more suited than a tuple for the list here, as on a set, membership is O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: @Lattyware - No, actually changing it to a set wouldn't make a difference, because we are testing for the membership in `attrs["show"]` (which may already be a set), not in the tuple I define for looping over the strings.  The only change is that you might check the strings in a different order.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, and `or` evaluates to its first `True` operand (since `True` or'd with anything is `True`, Python doesn't need to look further than the first operand).

So:

```
"aa" or "bb" or "cc" or "dd" or "ee" or "ff" in attrs["show"]
```

... evaluates to:

```
"aa"
```

Which is `True`, because it's a non-empty string. The rest of the line is not even considered because it does not need to be.

So your `if` statement always executes because it is always `True`.

What you want is something like:

```
"aa" in attrs["show"] or "bb" in attrs["show"] or "cc" in attrs["show"] ...
```

This gets very wordy, so you can use `any` along with a generator expression to write it more succinctly.

```
any(s in attrs["show"] for s in ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `IF` statement is not testing for anything. It **WILL** always evaluate as true, because of the way it is written.

You are asking python:

```
Is aa true
Is bb true
...
```

Python says 'Yes, "aa" is true, because its there!'

Correct your if statement or find a better way to find the values in the list:

```
any(x in ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'] for x in attrs["show"])
```

Comment: Your first part is right.  But `if ("aa" or "bb" ...) in attrs["show"]` is equivalent to `if "aa" in attrs["show"]`, so is not what you intended.

Comment: Your "corrected" `if` statement always looks for `"aa"` in `attrs["show"]` and your second example is logically backward.

Comment: @rubik Would you mind clarifying? My posted answer is a solution based on as much information as the question poster gave. I cannot create more information than what was given.

Comment: @kindall Based on the question presented, my first example gives expected output. `check if attrs["show"] contains either of these strings`. First example will enter the `if` block if any of the values are in `attrs["show"]`.

Comment: No, it does not. `("aa" or "bb" or "cc" or "dd" or "ee" or "ff") in attrs["show"]` is the same as `"aa" in attrs["show"]`.

Comment: @Kindall  Removed the first example.

Comment: Second example is still backward. You're checking whether each character of the string `attrs[show]` is in the list `['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']`. Since the list items are all two characters, this is always `False`.

Comment: @kindall You are incorrect. Try running the code: `>>> any(x in ['cc','dd','ee','ff'] for x in ["aa", "bb", "cc"])
True
>>> any(x in ['cc','dd','ee','ff'] for x in ["aa", "bb"])
False`

Comment: Ah, you assumed that `attrs["show"]` is a list. It'll work in that case. I assumed it was a string. In which case writing it the other way 'round is the only way it will work (and it also works fine when it's a list).

Comment: @kindall So more that you where correct *and* I was correct. Both though, under different assumptions of the `attrs['show']`. That's the problem with questions that don't specify enough I suppose.

Comment: Yes, agreed... specs are vital.